# Duvidas relacionamento muito para muitos laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.2

Tenho o seguinte relacionamento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha duvida vem na programação do model de  encomenda_produtos, o real gostaria de verificar se estou fazendo da maneira correta, programei assim:

```
class EncomendaProdutos extends Model
{
  use SoftDeletes;
  protected $fillable = [
    'CdEncomenda',
    'CdPessoa',
    'CdProduto',
    'CdPromo',
    'QtdProduto',
    'DescontoProdutos'
  ];

  protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

  public function produto()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Produto','CdProduto','CdProduto');

  }

  public function pessoa()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Tipo_Produto','CdTipoProduto','CdTipoProduto');

 }

 public function promocao()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Embalagem','CdEmbalagem','CdEmbalagem');

  }
 }
```

Pretendo poder pesquisar uma encomenda e ela me retorna todos produtos que foi encomendado, além de saber qual pessoa fez a encomenda, e ainda se ela esta ligada a uma promoção.

Nas outras model fiz assim:

```
Model Encomenda

class Encomenda extends Model
{
 use SoftDeletes;
 protected $fillable = [
    'CdPessoa',
    'Cidade',
    'Estado',
    'Bairro',
    'Rua',
    'Num',
    'Complemento',
    'CEP',
    'DescontoTotal',
    'VlTotal',
    'FlgStEncomenda',
    'FlgRepetirEntrega'
    ];
 protected $primaryKey = 'CdEncomenda';
 protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

 public function cliente()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Pessoa','CdPessoa','CdPessoa');
  }

 public function encomenda_produtos(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\EncomendaProdutos', 'CdEncomenda', 'CdEncomenda');
  }
}
```

E da mesma forma em `promocao`.

Esta certo a minha programação, este conhecimento não esta fixo em minha mente.

Um exemplo de utilização:

> Sou cliente comprei dois produto, então as tabelas deve ser salfas da seguinte maneira:

```
Encomenda
CdEncomenda 1
outros dados da tabela

/////////
EncomendaProdutos
CdEncomenda 1
CdProtudo 10

////

CdEncomenda 1
CdProduto 23
```

Comment: Nessa `encomenda_produtos` tipo eu sou cliente eu faço a compra de dois produtos ele vai gerar para cada produto uma determinada encomenda (`CdEncomenda`)?

Comment: não a ideia é que repita o cdencomenda, e ele gere 2

Comment: Como você vai controlar a geração desses número @RenanRodrigues?

Comment: Farei um foreach em m array de produtos e irei salvar automaticamente cada um.

Comment: Acho que entendi !!! se tem `encomendas` e `encomendas_produtos` o `CdPessoa` só precisa ter em encomendas!

Comment: Eu faria assim! encomendas_produtos com uma chave primaria, e um chave composta de encomendas e produtos, retira cdpessoa de encomendas_produtos!

Comment: Exato, encomendas produto so faz referencia aos produtos encomendados

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47206/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-renan-rodrigues).

Comment: Poderia preparar uma resposta ? completa com os relacionamentos

Comment: @VirgilioNovic me tire uma duvida dentro desta pergunta mesmo como faria para acessar os metodos dentro do encomenda_produtos, como por exemplo para pegar o nome do produto ?

Comment: os seus relacionamentos `hasOne` deveriam ser `belongsTo` porque não é herança que você está fazendo é 1 para muitos. eu não respondi nada na sua pergunta, por causa disso são muitos `models` para arrumar, e na hora que fui observar `promocoes` acabei embananando as idéias, porque tem categorias, sub categorias, em pensei será que isso está certo. No Laravel segue também a `3FN` e você me parece que não está seguindo isso, por esse motivo a pergunta ainda está em aberto.

Comment: Peço desculpas, sou um dos que respondem `Laravel`, mas, os seus relacionamentos eu fiquei muito confuso...